# Функция возвращающая массив Pascal

Tags: массивы, pascal, функции

Как сделать, что бы функция вернула массив.

```
function MessagesGet(json : string): array of  string;
begin
  var m : array of string; 
  m := json.Split('"', ':', ',');
  var mA: array[1..2] of string;
  mA[0] := m[19];
  mA[1] := m[34];
  //Нужно записать в массив MessagesGet mA[0] и mA[1]
end;
```

*Я не имею опыта работы с паскалем.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function MessagesGet(json: string): array of string;
var 
  m: array of string; 
begin
  m := json.Split('"', ':', ','); // это что? не знаю такого
  SetLength(result, 2);
  result[0] := m[19];
  result[1] := m[34];
end;
```